# How to make a div with position:fixed occupy the entire parent width (and resize with it)?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, stretching

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eEe2C/2/

The green row 1 is fixed but does not stretch the entire parent width which the other blue rows do. Think of row 1 as the column headers in a grid. It needs to be fixed in order to be visible at all times and for all rows to "slide" underneath it when scrolling. The only difference between row 1 and the other rows is that row 1 has position:fixed.

When resizing horizontally, the "cells" of the blue rows expand just fine according to their width percentage. The "cells" of the green row ignores this (I know why, just need a solution).

How do I get the same stretching behaviour for row 1 still keeping it fixed? The headers should of course be aligned with the data "cells". Please, no post-js hack if possible.

*Edit: can't use tables as I'm using drag'n'drop sorting that doesn't play well at all with tables.*

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use CSS to fake what an HTML table would do implicitly?

Comment: As far as i know this isn't possible without a JS hack.  But... i'm no expert.

Comment: Well, the rows are involved with a lot of drag'n'drop sorting which doesn't play well with tables. Also, I'm not able to style tables well cross-browser.

Comment: Setting width:100% on row1 makes it occupy the entire browser window which leads me to believe that there must be a way for it to occupy the entire width of some other parent element...? Any gurus?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it correctly, do you mean like this? Although you might want to set a specific width on the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/eEe2C/6/

Comment: Nope, I still need row1 to be position:fixed so that row1 stays in viewport no matter scrolling position.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe this is what you are seeking: http://jsfiddle.net/eEe2C/12/ Since there was no CSS reset, I think there was some default margin and padding, so i set the body to 0 for both. I added some background to see where the elements were, but you  can take those out.

Comment: Yes, works, but I really need a more generic solution where the parent container dictates the expansion width for all contained elements.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's a demo, it looks like tabular data to me so just use a `<table>`. Using a [table with a fixed height `<tbody>`](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) might be a good solution to your problem.